# How to create a super-huge file with pure c or linux-shell or dos-commands?

Tags: windows, linux, createfile

My os and drive is

```
OS: Windows XP sp2 or Linux SUSE 9 or Cygwin
Compiler: Visual C++ 2003 or Gcc or Cygwin
PC and os are both 32 bits
```

So, How can I create a super-huge file in secs

I was told to use MappingFile functions. I failed to create files over 2G
So...
Your warm responses will be all appreciated
thanks

Comment: Does it matter what the content is?

Comment: I mean, what are you trying to do? Just block space on the disk?

Comment: Can you please be a bit more specific on super-huge, and also describe about the contents!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using `dd` in Linux to create a 1 gb file takes 57 seconds 'wall clock time' on a somewhat loaded box with a slow disk, and about 17 seconds system time:

```
$ time dd if=/dev/zero of=bigfile bs=G count=1
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB) copied, 53.9903 s, 19.9 MB/s

real    0m56.685s
user    0m0.008s
sys     0m17.113s
$
```

Answer (score 4):

you can use dd

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=bigfile.txt bs=$((1024*1024)) count=100
```

or just plain shell scripting and contents doesn't matter

```
1) create a dummy file with a few lines, eg 10 lines
2) use cat dummy >> bigfile in a while loop

eg

    while true
    do
      cat dummy >> bigfile.txt 
      #check for number of lines more than 10000 for example and break out of loop
    done
```

Do another time

```
while true
do
  cat bigfile >> bigfile2.txt           
  # check for size and break out..
done
rm -f dummy bigfile
```

Comment: `/dev/zero` is likely to be faster than `/dev/random`, and easier for whatever is consuming the file to deal with.

Comment: Agreed, /dev/random can block, if psuedo random content is needed its better to use /dev/urandom.

Answer (score 2):

Does the file have to take up actual disk space?  If not, you could always (in Cygwin, or Linux):

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=bigfile seek=7T bs=1 count=1
```

This will create an empty 7 TB file in a fraction of a second.  Of course, it won't allocate much actual disk space:  You'll have a big [sparse file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file).

Writing a program under Cygwin or Linux, you can do the same thing in a C program with a call to [ftruncate](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/ftruncate.html).

Comment: Couldn't find a great man page quickly.  In Linux, calling ftruncate with a size larger than the file always extends the file's size.  Pretty sure Cygwin adheres to this.

Comment: Even if it didn't, it's fairly easy to use a pair of `fseek(HUGE)` and `fwrite(a byte)` to achieve the same thing.

Comment: You need to make sure cygwin has the filesystem mounted with sparse support first - https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#mount-table

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your system limits you can create a largefile in a fraction of a second...

```
FILE *fp = fopen("largefile" ,"w");
for(int i = 0; i < 102400; i++)
{
    fseek(fp, 10240000, SEEK_CUR);
}
fprintf(fp, "%c", 'x');
fclose(fp);
```

Play with this.

Comment: is it a little time-consuming?

Answer (score 2):

cat /dev/urandom >> /home/mybigfile

It will error out when disc space has ran out.

This is for linux/bsd/possibly cgywin

Answer (score 1):

In suse in a VM I did `dd if=/dev/zero of=file;rm file` which filled the disk, and when it was full deleted the file. This allowed me to compress the image a little more for some reason, and I read about doing it on a forum somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "fsutil" command for Win2000/XP/7:

c:> **fsutil** file createnew
Usage : fsutil file createnew  
   Eg : fsutil file createnew C:\testfile.txt 1000

Reagrds

Answer (score 0):

If you want a sparse file you can do that also on Windows (on NTFS volumes), using CreateFile, DeviceIOFunction with FSCTL_SET_SPARSE and FSCTL_SET_ZERO_DATA; for more info see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365566%28VS.85%29.aspx).